# Can't create docker file and Project file using Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I need to create an Azure function project via Docker. I learned something about the docker commands for creating the function app project and templates.

I already installed the docker and related SDKs in my system.

I used this command for create function with docker file "**func init . --docker**" but it'd not working properly,
[image]

[image]
This is the files created without the docker file, I don't know why it's not create.

After that I execute the "**func new**" command for creating the function with language and Function Templates also selected,

[image]

[image]

And also not create the project(*.csproj) file.
I executed the commands properly but why it's not coming I don't know about it. Please give me a solution for this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this up and running in WSL
As stated in the [readme](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) one should make sure everything is set up correctly.

1. Start up WSL
2. run `wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

   - This will download a file needed to install azure functions correctly.
3. run `sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb` to install the previously downloaded package.
4. run `sudo apt-get update` to update your local aptitude cache.
5. run `sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools` to install the azure functions core tools.
6. Make sure dotnet is installed: run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2`
7. Run `func init . --docker` and select dotnet as framework (option 1)

This will result into a list of files in your current directory:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
└── test.csproj

0 directories, 4 files
```

You can now create an Azure function by running `func new`. Select a template (`HttpTrigger`, option 2), provide a name `SampleFunction` and you have your function ready.

Your directory now looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── SampleFunction.cs
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
└── test.csproj

0 directories, 5 files
```

This is all done with `func` version **2.3.199**

Comment: Thanks for reply, but, is this windows container or linux. Because I already installed all the things from your provide the link based with the windows. you mention your answer with linux also??? And also I'm working for function app core.

Comment: This is done with WSL on windows as linux containers. Did you use the v1 or v2 npm package? If v2 the steps after step 6 will/should be the same if i'm correct. Can you run `func --version` in powershell? Regarding windows/linux containers.. Did you install docker on windows and use 'linux containers' or did you explicitly change the setting to use windows containers? If the first you should get the same results, if the latter you should aswell but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: Yeah! I tried all the steps that link provided for windows. And also configured the docker in my system properly. But, the expected results are not came. You provided the linux based configuration, I no need that so, I posted the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply.